Adding a multi-dimensional column to a pandas dataframe
I have two dataframes which look something like the following:
issue_df

    COL1  COL2                 REF
0  Name1  Val1        [REF1, REF2]
1  Name2  Val2                None
2  Name3  Val3  [REF1, REF2, REF3]
3  Name4  Val4                REF2

ref_df

   NAME  SCORE
0  REF1  100.0
1  REF2   99.0
2  REF3   85.0

I want to iterate through the rows of issue_df and query the ref_df for the values in the REF column and create a new merged data frame like the following output:
merged_df

    COL1  COL2                 REF  REF_INFO
0  Name1  Val1        [REF1, REF2]  REF1 : 100.0
                                    REF2 : 99.0
1  Name2  Val2                None  None
2  Name3  Val3  [REF1, REF2, REF3]  REF1 : 100.0
                                    REF2 : 99.0
                                    REF3 : 85.0
3  Name4  Val4                REF2  REF2 : 99.0

Then ideally I would be able to query this merged_df for any row where it has a ref where the score is less than a certain amount.
I've tried creating this as a dictionary first, where REF_INFO includes a column of nested dictionaries and then converting it to a dataframe, but this produces errors and warnings.
Test code I'm using:
import pandas as pd

issue_data = {
    'COL1': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4'],
    'COL2': ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4'],
    'REF': [['REF1', 'REF2'], None, ['REF1', 'REF2', 'REF3'], 'REF2']}
ref_data = {
    'NAME': ['REF1', 'REF2', 'REF3'],
    'SCORE': [100.0, 99.0, 85.0]}

issue_df = pd.DataFrame(issue_data)
ref_df = pd.DataFrame(ref_data)

Any ideas on how to accomplish what I'm going for?

You can explode on column 'REF' of issue_df, then map the values from ref_df:
merged_df = issue_df.explode("REF")
merged_df["REF_INFO"] = merged_df["REF"].map(ref_df.set_index("NAME")["SCORE"])

    COL1  COL2   REF  REF_INFO
0  Name1  Val1  REF1     100.0
0  Name1  Val1  REF2      99.0
1  Name2  Val2     -       NaN
2  Name3  Val3  REF1     100.0
2  Name3  Val3  REF2      99.0
2  Name3  Val3  REF3      85.0
3  Name4  Val4  REF2      99.0

Then query merged_df to get rows less than a certain value:
merged_df.query("REF_INFO < 100")

    COL1  COL2   REF  REF_INFO
0  Name1  Val1  REF2      99.0
2  Name3  Val3  REF2      99.0
2  Name3  Val3  REF3      85.0
3  Name4  Val4  REF2      99.0


If the query should include other 'REF_INFO' values for the same original row, you can instead get the index of the items that match the query and use that to filter merged_df:
f = merged_df.query("REF_INFO < 90").index.values
q = merged_df[merged_df.index.isin(f)]

    COL1  COL2   REF  REF_INFO
2  Name3  Val3  REF1     100.0
2  Name3  Val3  REF2      99.0
2  Name3  Val3  REF3      85.0


The way I understood the question, the query should include other REF_INFO values for the same original row too, e.g. 100.0 in row 0. I'm not sure how to do that cleanly; I'm stumbling my own way to an answer rn :p

@wjandrea I think you're right. I've edited the question to address that.

Thanks for the response. I had considered this solution and may have to resort to it if I can't find something that produces the example output I am looking for. I was going to do it in a much dirtier way though. This is a lot cleaner than what I was imagining I would do.
Ideally though I would like to keep the output as a data frame where each item from issue_df remains a single row, so I can take a count on how many items in the merged_df have a score below a threshold (in addition to printing the relevant rows). If it's exploded like this, it will multi-count the items from issue_df.

@Peregrin5 Once you explode a dataframe, the original index is also duplicated for the duplicated rows. So you can use nunique on the index to get the count of original rows that remain in the resulting dataframe q: q.index.nunique()

@e-motta Awesome this helps a lot. I am curious to see if anyone is able to get the data frame I outlined in the question, but if no one else responds in a few hours, I'll probably mark this as the accepted answer.
